# Linux host configuration for continuous deployment?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu-16.04, continuous-integration

We are in the process of setting up a host for continuous deployment. Each application runs under its own user account.

Currently the approach we are looking at is simply allowing the continuous build machine to have publickey to that application's account for purpose of deployment.

There is concern that this may create a vulnerability, so we are trying to see if there are ways of reducing risk. Limiting the access to IPv4 block is not really an option, due to clustered nature of our third-party build service, so we need to consider other risk mitigation approaches, as part of our deployment process. I don't want the benefits of continuous deployment to harm our production environment.

Can anyone suggest approaches that can provide the CI machines the ability to do their job, while ensuring we aren't opening up a security hole. Ideally approaches that have been used in an environment you respect, as to avoid purely theoretical approaches.

Deployment host is using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, based VM with access via ssh. Server will be hosting a web facing HTTP based application.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SSH key the way you are is not necessarily a bad way to go. If you're really concerned you could split the deployment account from the credentials used to actually run the service.

Are you building a new server each time or reusing an existing one? The second is less likely to accumulate configuration changes that leave you open but with out more information about your pipeline this is a hard question to answer.

Comment: For the deployment host, each environment (dev, staging, prod) has its own VM and it is reused. For CI they create a new VM for each run. I had wondered whether to use a specific user for all deployments, but then it opens up the issue of permissions to relaunch process, etc, potentially creating other issues?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to force a command to be run on connection, which can limit what can be done with the key.  There are a number of other options that can be applied including limiting the source IP for the connection.  See your man page for `authorized_keys` and/or `sshd` for details.

For a use like this you may want to force a command to pull the deployment into the environment.  The deployment can be specified in the connection request, or you may be able to pull the latest file.

You may want to provide the deployments via NFS, or use scp to push or pull the build.